# GitHub "permission denied" message, even though key has been added?

Tags: git, github, ssh

On my local machine, I can push to a git repo with no problems, without being asked for a passphrase.

On the remote machine, whenever I try to push, I get the dreaded:

```
-bash-4.1$ git pull origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` are the same on both machines. If I try to add the key to my GitHub account, GitHub tells me it's already been added.

Why can I access the repo on one machine, and not the other?

Here's what I get when I try to ssh to github on the remote machine:

```
-bash-4.1$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.131] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/apsmith/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/apsmith/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/apsmith/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/apsmith/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/apsmith/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/apsmith/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/apsmith/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

On the remote machine, the following files are in the ~/.ssh directory:

```
-bash-4.1$ ls ~/.ssh/
authorized_keys  id_dsa.pub       id_rsa.pub       known_hosts
```

Comment: NB: there is no private key on the remote machine, that's because it's a server to which other people have access. Weirdly I was able to access GitHub from this remote machine just last week, so I don't know what has changed.

Comment: Why the downvote? :( I won't know why this is a poor question unless people at least comment. :(

Comment: Try this on your remote machine https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: If I replace the existing ssh public key on the remote machine, won't that mean I can no longer ssh into the remote machine from my local machine?

Comment: Hey Richard, did you ever solve this issue? I am experiencing the same thing. On friday my github ssh worked fine and on tuesday access denied with now changes in between. My ssh -vT git@github.com looks essentially just like yours.